# Reach Related Entities' Attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I get an entity list by following:

```
var riscregions = db.RiscEntranceDetails.OrderBy(r => r.RiscEntranceID).Include(r => r.RiscEntrance).Include(r => r.RiscRegion);
```

However, I need to reach more deeply related entities attributes, such as:

```
<td>@item.RiscEntrance.ID</td>
<td>@item.RiscEntrance.Personnel.Name</td>
<td>@item.RiscEntrance.EntranceDateTime</td>
<td>@item.RiscEntrance.ShiftWork.ShiftGroup.TextID</td>
```

How can I reach those? Any suggestions including linq, or some other workarounds such as extensions and helpers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var riscregions = db.RiscEntranceDetails
                .OrderBy(r => r.RiscEntranceID)
                .Include(r => r.RiscEntrance)
                .Include(r => r.RiscEntrance.Personnel)
                .Include(r => r.RiscEntrance.ShiftWork.ShiftGroup)
```

You need to use `Select` in your `Include` expression only if you need to select children of a collection.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan You can edit my answer to correct it if something is still not right.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan No problem. That's what SO is for. I would delete the comments now, since they don't add anything new to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

See eagerly loading multiple levels. You can use `.Select()` in your `.Include()` lambda.

Comment: Thanks but answer of @david.s looks better to me. +1 for the great link.